# Import Microsoft Exchange Online PowerShell Module

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

Previously, I used to connect PowerShell to Windows Azure Active Directory and Exchange Online using the following BAT file:

```
@echo off 
Powershell -noexit -Command "& {
    $Credentials = Get-Credential;
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Authentication Basic -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -AllowRedirection:$true -Credential $Credentials;
    Import-PSSession $Session;
    Import-Module MSOnline;
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $Credentials;
}"
```

This worked great until we enabled MFA / TFA on our global administrator accounts which then caused the above BAT file to fail with the following errors:

```
New-PSSession : [ps.outlook.com] Connecting to remote server ps.outlook.com failed with the following error message :
[ClientAccessServer=VI1PR0701CA0070,BackEndServer=amspr03mb326.eurprd03.prod.outlook.com,RequestId=f875eba9-7066-45df-9d59-67f9daf8b210,TimeStamp=9/7/2017 7:57:14 AM] Access Denied For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:66
+ ...  $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Auth ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2144108477,PSSessionOpenFailed
Import-PSSession : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:1 char:256
+ ... ion:$true -Credential $Credentials; Import-PSSession $Session; Import ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Import-PSSession], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportPSSessionCommand

Connect-MsolService : Authentication Error: Authentication cancelled by user.
At line:1 char:290
+ ... Import-Module MSOnline; Connect-MsolService -Credential $Credentials}
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService
```

According to Microsoft's TechNet article ["Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell using multi-factor authentication"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt775114(v=exchg.160).aspx), I need to (**only using a Microsoft web browser**, no less) install the "[Microsoft] Exchange Online [Remote] PowerShell Module".

I have done so and confirmed that I can now connect PowerShell to Exchange Online using an MFA- / TFA-enabled administrator account.

However, I want to incorporate the new PowerShell module into my original BAT file but I'm not sure whether it's possible because:

1. Research has yielded nothing relevant.
2. The Start Menu entry `Microsoft Exchange Online Powershell Module` is a `APPREF-MS` / ClickOnce file that seemingly doesn't point to any local file.
3. Command `Get-Module –ListAvailable` doesn't output anything that contains `EXOP`.

Can anyone advise?

**Update 2017/09/08 10:10**:

I:

1. Read that ClickOnce applications were stored in the folder `%localAppData%\Apps\2.0\`.
2. Searched the folder `%localAppData%\Apps\2.0\` for `*.ps1`.
3. Found the file `C:\Users\%userName%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\N8Z7NPYM.QVD\BL0EGO2J.G5A\micr..tion_51a5b647dacf4059_0010.0000_5d32306b9385c20a\CreateExoPSSession.ps1`.
4. Searched the file `C:\Users\%userName%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\N8Z7NPYM.QVD\BL0EGO2J.G5A\micr..tion_51a5b647dacf4059_0010.0000_5d32306b9385c20a\CreateExoPSSession.ps1` for `Connect-EXOPSSession`.
5. Found the lines:

   ```
   $ExoPowershellModule = "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellModule.dll";
   $ModulePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, $ExoPowershellModule);

   $global:ConnectionUri = $ConnectionUri;
   $global:AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri = $AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri;
   $global:UserPrincipalName = $UserPrincipalName;
   $global:PSSessionOption = $PSSessionOption;

   Import-Module $ModulePath;
   $PSSession = New-ExoPSSession -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -ConnectionUri $ConnectionUri -AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri $AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri -PSSessionOption $PSSessionOption

   if ($PSSession -ne $null)
           {
               Import-PSSession $PSSession -AllowClobber
               UpdateImplicitRemotingHandler
           }
   ```
6. Searched the folder `%localAppData%\Apps\2.0\` for `microsoft.exchange.management.exopowershellmodule.dll`.
7. Found the file `C:\Users\%userName%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\N8Z7NPYM.QVD\BL0EGO2J.G5A\micr..tion_51a5b647dacf4059_0010.0000_5d32306b9385c20a\Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellModule.dll`.
8. Copied all files from folder `C:\Users\%userName%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\N8Z7NPYM.QVD\BL0EGO2J.G5A\micr..tion_51a5b647dacf4059_0010.0000_5d32306b9385c20a` to folder `C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\modules\Exo`.
9. Executed commands:

   ```
   Import-Module "C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\modules\Exo\Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellModule.dll"
   New-ExoPSSession
   ```
10. Authenticated via MFA.
11. Found that PowerShell ouputted the following:

    ```
     Id Name            ComputerName    ComputerType    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
     -- ----            ------------    ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
      1 WinRM1          outlook.offi... RemoteMachine   Opened        Microsoft.Exchange       Available
    ```
12. Found that commands such as `Get-Mailbox` and `Get-InboxRule` were failing with the following errors:

    ```
     %cmdlet% : The term '%cmdlet%' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
     At line:1 char:1
     + %cmdlet%
     + ~~~~~~~~~~~
         + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (%cmdlet%:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    ```

So, we're getting somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking to do the same thing, and I came across [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/richardroddy/2018/04/04/using-powershell-ise-to-connect-to-exchange-online-when-mfa-is-enabled/). Simply running these two commands within a normal PowerShell window allowed me to connect to Exchange Online (with MFA-enabled):

```
$CreateEXOPSSession = (Get-ChildItem -Path $env:userprofile -Filter CreateExoPSSession.ps1 -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Select -Last 1).DirectoryName

. "$CreateEXOPSSession\CreateExoPSSession.ps1"
```

I could then connect using

```
Connect-EXOPSSession
```

Comment: I've confirmed that a BAT file with contents `@echo off & Powershell -noexit -Command "& {$CreateEXOPSSession = (Get-ChildItem -Path $env:userprofile -Filter CreateExoPSSession.ps1 -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Select -Last 1).DirectoryName; . "$CreateEXOPSSession\CreateExoPSSession.ps1"; Connect-EXOPSSession; Connect-MsolService; }"` works. While it isn't ideal because it prompts for authentication twice (once for each service), there seems to not be an easy way around this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing Exchange Online PowerShell module, you can use Exchange Online PowerShell V2 module.

Currently, I am using EXO V2 module. You can directly install the module from PowerShell gallery.

```
    Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
```

You can connect to Exchange Online PowerShell using below cmdlet.

```
    Connect-ExchangeOnline
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by the following;

From your step 7:  I did not copy the files at all. I left them where they were. There is no reason why they would not work after copy but I rebuild this machine quite often so wanted to reduce steps.

My Step 8: In the ISE (in my case the directory name is as follows)
`cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\V7MK47Q8.0NZ\KLJLETPC.4RJ\micr..tion_d8f8f667ee342b5c_0010.0000_6b4a13fd451b1c00
Import-Module .\CreateExoPSSession.ps1
Connect-EXOPSSession -UserPrincipalName name@domain.com`

Now, there is no reason why this should work as it is not a proper module but it does and has been for a while now.

I can not post a picture as I have no rep but suffice to say when you use "connect-", the first two in the list are AzureAD and EXOPSSession.